# Javascript Next/Prev Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 2;
    $("#n_next").click(function(){
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
        i++;
    });

     $("#n_prev").click(function(){
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
        i--;
    });
});
</script>

<div><img id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/zeitvergleich/1/before.jpg" width="540" height="360" /> <img id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/zeitvergleich/1/after.jpg" width="540" height="360" /></div>
<img src="img/prev.png" id="n_prev"/> <img src="img/next.png" id="n_next"/>
```

This is not my script. Someone helped me to make it work at least for the "next" button. But the problem is I cant figure out how I get it worked with "prev" button too.

Now when I press next it works fine. But when I press prev he first make i++ (So goes to the next 2 pictures) and then he goes 1 picture back.

Hope you know what I did wrong and you can help me :)
And sorry for my bad englisch.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: "*Hey guys this is my script*"/"*This is not my script*" - um..?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I was just making one but problem is solved, thanks anyway

Comment: @DavidThomas I mean it is my script. I just didnt made him by myself. Someone helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `i` index tracking. Try incrementing/decrementing in the beginning!
QUick and dirty fix:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $("#n_next").click(function(){
        i++;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });

     $("#n_prev").click(function(){
        i--;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });
});
</script>
```

Update: for a little cleaner structure try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    var showImageSet = function (index) {
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/'+index+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/"+index+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    };

    $("#n_next").click(function(){
        i++;
        showImageSet(i);
    });

     $("#n_prev").click(function(){
        i--;
        showImageSet(i);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfekt! Thanks a lot :)

Do you know if there is a way I can show the var "i"?
So I can put it under the pictures to see wich number it is.

Comment: Sure you could use it in other places, but you need to decide where and in which form. For starters, try adding this to the `showImageSet` function block:

`$("#changer1").attr("alt","Nr. "+index+" before");
    $("#changer2").attr("alt","Nr. "+index+" after");` and then hover the mouse over the picture.

Comment: You are a good man :D
Thank you very much. This is all I needed

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem then don't forget to mark it as accepted answer ;)